# Which cables I need to extend the Samsung Note 3 screen to the monitor (DVI-D dual link)

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, dvi, cable, smartphone

I'm looking for a solution to connect my smart phone Samsung Galaxy Note 3 to my monitor Acer S220HQL. This monitor has two connectors:

1. VGA
2. DVI-D dual link

Actually the VGA connector is busy but the DVI-D dual link not and I want to use it to extend the screen of the Note 3 on the monitor and I wanna know which kind of cables I need.

Answer (score 0):

@Marietto - there's a discussion on this topic that matches your use case: http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-note-3/319181-what-needed-hdmi-out-note-3-a.html

It suggests you will need an MHL adapter but some people seem to have trouble with it and one person indicated the quality wasn't as expected.

Comment: I tried to read but it's a mess. I want to try these adapters,tell me what you think :

1) from the DVI-D dual link to VGA : 

http://www.ebay.com/bhp/dvi-d-dual-link-to-vga

2) from MHL to VGA 

http://www.amazon.ca/Cable-Matters-Adapter-Samsung-Galaxy/dp/B00ESM3VXO

could it work ? thanks.

Comment: I haven't tried either myself.  My Samsung Galaxy 2 might have one of those ports, but I havn't tried to connect it to a monitor (though now I want to).  My suggestion would be to go to a local computer store where they are likely to have both the cables and a VGA compatible monitor and try before you buy.

Comment: Just based on what others are saying though, the MHL to VGA would be the first thing I would try.  Just keep your receipt if you have to return it.

Comment: this could be the right scenario for me : http://robwillis.info/2013/08/samsung-note-2-hdmivga-out-to-a-tvcomputer-monitor-via-mhl/

Comment: Please,check at min. 2.57 of this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PN4akeB0VrY and tell me which kind of adapter is located in the middle ? thanks.

Comment: The one in the middle is HDMI to SVGA - that's the one in his right hand at 2:52.  The other is the HDMI (Female) to MHL (male) which connects to the phone.  So he's using two adapters to get the job done.  That could work.  Would be cool if you could by MHL to SVGA... maybe someone makes one.

Comment: FYI - there will necessarily be some loss of fidelity with this setup.